# How to ensure that the user cannot log in from another device or browser that is not defined?

Tags: security, authentication, logging, notifications

I want my user not to be able to log in from another device or browser, after identifying this device on which he is logged in to him. With which technologies and libraries can I achieve this?

For example, when user A enters on the phone, he / she cannot log in on the computer at the same time.

And I want the administration to be notified when user B tries to login with the information of user A.

I am open to all kinds of information.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Login to web apps is usually done using cookies, that store `session id` of some kind.

You can just deauthorise the old session after new login or have some simple logic with timestamp of last request and session id.

Any web technology stack can do this.

To get device id, you can use this in javascript:
`var deviceID = MediaDeviceInfo.deviceId;`

To monitor live user connections in realtime, use sockets eg: (Node.js + Socket.io)

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know, if you want to get device specific information like phone's IMEI, this is possible only using native phone apps, which is different depending on platform & device you're building for. in case of web apps i don't know any ways to identify devices from each other by device id. so let's put aside device-specific information & implement our own way of recognizing devices to prevent sign-in on multiple devices through only one account.

because you asked your question tech-agnostic so i just describe what i came up with, not with libraries, codes & algorithm. you can implement this on technology of your choice.

**let me describe the method**:
we need a place to store a token specific to each user after login at user side. so we could use header or cookie. i think using cookie is easier to implement because setting header on every request is painful, like for example you need to add parameters to get requests for passing this token to server.

so using a cookie, you need to generate a token in your backend after user login, and store it in database for that user & pass it to client as cookie.
for each request to be considered valid, the token in cookie should match the one in the logged-in user database, otherwise logout the user & notify the supervisor through an email for example.
for each validated request(token in cookie matches the one in database) you have to revoke this token & store it in database in place of the previous one so the old token expires in this way & update the user cookie with the revoked token.

how this prevents from multiple logged-in devices? when a user logins with account credentials on other devices or other agents, the token will be revoked & when the old device makes a request the tokens do not match so the implemented codes logs the user out & if it tries to log back in, the same will happen for the second device & so on. the scenario is the same for any number of devices, if login credentials is shared among many, only one can be logged-in at a time.

this method does not gives us device-specific information, but it solves the issue of having multiple devices logged-in at a time.

- for security measures, encrypt the cookie.
- the token revokes on each requests so it could not be shared alongside credentials
- when user logs out the token field should be cleared & cleared token field signs an OK login action for any device with these credentials

sorry if it became long, best regards ;)